# Why TCP RST packet generated what are the possible cause

Tags: networking

when TCP RST packet generated? what are the possible cause of generation on TCP RST packet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RST flag is used to signal any kind of error and terminate the connection.

- If you send a packet with a wrong ACK, you will get a RST
- If you don't acknowledge data in a timely manner, you get a RST

Basically, if you do anything wrong, a `TCP` will send a `RST` and terminate the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that Linux Kernel sent these RSTs.

An example: 
http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/12/hand-crafting-tcp-handshake-with-scapy.html